# Cygwin html to browser

Tags: c, linux, windows, sockets, cygwin

I've written a c socket program in c (cygwin) and I want to send some html code to my browser.

I've written the server and if i run it and type in my browser `localhost:8888`. My program says it sends the correct amount of bytes but my browser seems to receive nothing.

send code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>   //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>  //write

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , new_socket , c;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char *message;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("bind failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 1);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
    if (new_socket<0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connection accepted");


    char *reply = 
    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n<Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n<body>\r\n<h1>My First Heading</h1>\r\n<p>My first paragraph.</p>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>";
    int i = send(new_socket,reply,strlen(reply),0);
    printf("%d",i);
    shutdown(new_socket,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output program:

> bind done
>
> Waiting for incoming connections
>
> Connection accepted
>
> 98

Output browser:

> Error 103 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED): Unknown Error

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that, unless there's some more code you aren't showing us, your program isn't generating appropriate HTTP headers on the response. A minimal HTTP response would look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

Your HTML code goes here
```

Each line should be terminated by CR+LF (`\r\n`), and there must be two CR+LF pairs (e.g, `\r\n\r\n`) between the last header and the start of the body.

Comment: You also need to wait for an HTTP request to be sent before you generate a response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example web server in C](https://github.com/shenfeng/tiny-web-server) that you should take a look at.

It shows how the HTTP protocol, transported via TCP, is used to communicate between the browser and the web server.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send data to a browser your server needs to implement the HTTP protocol. This means waiting for a request from the browser, parsing it and then sending a response containing your data back to the browser.

Take a look at these useful resources about HTTP:

- [HTTP Made Really Easy](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/)
- [HTTP Protocol Standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)

The first one in particular provides very easy to understand information.